# In Linux distribution the list of timezones is empty

Tags: systemd, timezone, yocto

In a **yocto-base Linux distribution** is available the program `timedatectl` and it is necessary to set the timezone.
To do that exist the command:

```
timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>
```

The execution of the command `timedatectl list-timezones` to get the list of all timezones available outputs a list empty:

```
> timedatectl list-timezones
UTC
```

The distribution doesn't include any file `/usr/share/zoneinfo` or `/usr/zoneinfo`.

I think I miss installing something but I don't know what..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to set the timezone in my yocto-base Linux distribution. I need to install a package called `tzdata` by the following assignment:

```
# In the following assignment note the space before the package name "tzdata" 
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " tzdata"
```

By this new package the command `timedatectl list-timezones` lists all timezones available.

In particular in my distribution the info about timezones are stored in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

Comment: Yes, `/usr/share/zoneinfo` is the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html#specificOptions15)-compliant location for timezone information. That is the expected location for it in most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you have the tzdata package installed?

```
dpkg --get-selections  |grep tzdata
```

If not, you should install it.

```
sudo apt install tzdata
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm using a custom Linux build by yocto so I can't use a package manager (as `apt`) to install a package.

Comment: Thanks for your tips: the name of the package for Linux is `tzdata` the same used by a standard distribution with a package manager.